# Extjs3.4 Combobox store reload confusing

Tags: extjs, extjs3

It is actually a external window, the first time click open the window, the combobox are contain the value but the second and third times is no longer anymore. May i knw how to reload my combobox?

Tried few ways to reload the combobox, but failed, please gv me some idea. 
Below is my code.

> ```
> ViewUserRole = Ext.extend(One.Report, {
> reportName : '.ViewUserRoles',
> customModelName : 'Standard Role',
> autoExecute: true,
> isDetailPage: false,
> listeners: {
>     bbarconfig: function(report, bbarConfig) {
>       bbarConfig.items.push({
>         xtype: 'button',
>         text: 'Create New Role',
>         disabled: false,
>         listeners: {
>             click : function(btn, e) {
>                 var w = new .CreateNewUserRole();
>                 w.show();
>             }
>         }
>       });
>     }
> }
> });
> One.PageMgr.regDetail('Role', '.ViewUserRole');
> ```

```
// To call new Create User Role Form
CreateNewUserRole = new Ext.extend(Ext.Window,{
    id:'CreateNewUserRole',
    height :250,
    minHeight: 220,
    width:550,
    minWidth: 500,
    modal:true,
    title: Form_NewRole,
    layout: 'form',
    plain: true,
    initComponent: function() {
        this.items = [new .CreateUserRoleForm()];
        .CreateNewUserRole.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
    },
    bodyStyle: 'padding:5px;',
    buttonAlign: 'center',
    buttons: [{
        text: Button_ReadMe,
        listeners: {
            click : function(btn, e) {
                Ext.MessageBox.show({
                    title: Header_Information,
                    msg: Msg_CreateUserRoleNameExplain,
                    buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK,
                    icon: Ext.MessageBox.INFO
                 });
            }    
        }
    },{
        text: Button_Save,
        handler:function(){

            Ext.Ajax.request({ 
                url: '/oms/rest/manageuserrole/addnewrole', 
                params: { 
                    enterpriseId: enterpriseId, organizationId: organizationId
                }, 
                method: 'GET', 
                success: function() {
                    Ext.Msg.alert(Msg_SuccessfullyCreatedUserRole);
                    Ext.getCmp('CreateNewUserRole').close();
                }, 
                failure: function(response, opts) { 
                    Ext.MessageBox.show({
                        title: Header_Error,
                        msg: 'Server-side failure with status code ' + response.status,
                        buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK,
                        icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR
                    });
                }, 
                scope: this             
            }); 
        }
    },{
        text: Button_Cancel,
        handler:function(){
            Ext.getCmp('CreateNewUserRole').close();
        }
    }]
});


// Get All Enterprise List from Database
var enterpriseListStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    autoLoad: true,
    url: '/oms/rest/getEntOrgList/getEnterpriseList',
    root    : 'enterprise',
    fields  :[{name: "enterpriseID", type: "int"},{name: "enterpriseName", type: "string"}]

});

//Get All Organization List from Database
var organizationListStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    autoLoad: true,
    url: '/oms/rest/getEntOrgList/getOrganizationList',
    root    : 'organization',
    fields  :[{name: "organizationID", type: "int"},{name: "organizationName", type: "string"}]
});

// Create User Role Design
CreateUserRoleForm = Ext.extend(Ext.form.FormPanel, {
      initComponent : function() {
          this.items = [{
                xtype           : 'combo',
                id              : 'EnterpriseSel',
                fieldLabel      : Field_Enterprise,
                name            : 'enterprise',
                displayField    : 'enterpriseName',
                valueField      : 'enterpriseID',
                baseCls         : 'fwd_floatLeft',
                anchor          : '75%',
                queryMode       : 'local',
                mode            : 'local',
                editable        : false,
                triggerAction   : 'all',
                listClass       : 'comboalign',
                typeAhead       : true,
                labelWidth      : 50,
                hiddenName      : 'number',
                selectOnFocus   : true,
                store           : new Ext.data.JsonStore({
                storeId         : 'enterpriseListStoreId',
                autoLoad        : false,
                url             : '/oms/rest/getEntOrgSiteList/getEnterpriseList',
                root            : 'enterprise',
                fields          :[{name: "enterpriseID", type: "int"},{name: "enterpriseName", type: "string"}]
            }),
                listeners       : {
                    change:    function(field, newValue, oldValue){ 
                        organizationListStore.load();
                    }
                }
            },{
                xtype           : 'combo',
                id              : 'OrganizationSel',
                fieldLabel      : Field_Organization,
                name            : 'organization',
                displayField    : 'organizationName',
                valueField      : 'organizationID',
                baseCls         : 'fwd_floatLeft',
                anchor          : '75%',
                queryMode       : 'local',
                mode            : 'local',
                editable        : false,
                triggerAction   : 'all',
                listClass       : 'comboalign',
                typeAhead       : true,
                labelWidth      : 50,
                hiddenName      : 'number',
                selectOnFocus   : true,
                store           : organizationListStore
            }];

          CreateUserRoleForm.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
      } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all,

```
CreateNewUserRole = new Ext.extend(Ext.Window,{
```

should be changed to

```
CreateNewUserRole = Ext.extend(Ext.Window,{
```

And where is the definition of Combobox to see if there is any problem with it? It can be possible that you have specified static "id" to the combobox in CreateUserRoleForm.

You can define your stores with a storeId -

```
var enterpriseListStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    autoLoad: true,
    storeId : "enterprise-lists",
    url: '/oms/rest/getEntOrgList/getEnterpriseList',
    root    : 'enterprise',
    fields  :[{name: "enterpriseID", type: "int"},{name: "enterpriseName", type: "string"}]
});

var organizationListStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    autoLoad: true,
    storeId : "organization-lists",
    url: '/oms/rest/getEntOrgList/getOrganizationList',
    root    : 'organization',
    fields  :[{name: "organizationID", type: "int"},{name: "organizationName", type: "string"}]
});
```

so that they won't be destroyed even when the windows are closed.

Comment: i has included the combobox code, kindly advice me how to do only the combobox able to refresh when i click on the "Create New Role" button.

Comment: It could be that the stores being destroyed when the window is closed. You can move the definition of the two stores into initComponent method OR specify a **storeId** value for both the stores so that they are preserved. Second option is the best in your case as the data doesn't need to be reloaded every time the window is open.

Comment: about your second option, i think this is the right way to do, but do do you mind to explain more to me. sorry i'm not so familiar on combobox.

Comment: tried add the storeId but still same, then i try set autoDestroy as false and it work. Is that any issue will cause by autoDestroy?

Comment: Oh ok, got it. `autoDestroy : true` will make the store destroyed when the component it's bound to is destroyed. It's the default value. If your store is used with only a single component, then it should be true (default) so that the store won't be exist in memory when it's not used. In your case, as you want the store to not be destroyed everytime the window is destroyed, autoDestroy: false will do for you.